# I have a problem with typing

Tags: keyboard

Sometimes when I am typing the keyboard suddenly vanishes and the blinking line at the place where I was typing also disappears. Even after persistent tapping it doesn't respond (right when I was typing this very sentence it happened). It doesn't matter what keyboard I use, be it Swiftkey or Stock Android keyboard.

Can someone please help me. I really want to see my phone the way it was before.

Comment: See if clearing the cache and data (you would lose your dictionary so back it up to cloud using the keyboard settings)  helps

Comment: @beeshyams I have cleared cache. But clear data for what? Swiftkey? Android Stock?

Comment: For both . This may clear the problem - one of those things that usually helps

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work @beeshyams. Thanks for the help you provided so far, but can you help me out a bit more?

Comment: *Touch and hold delay*  on accessibility (under settings). See if changing settings there helps

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks anyway. I decided to factory reset my phone to get rid of a lot of problems. Thank you so much for your help nontheless.

Answer (score 1):

When mine does this I am able to double-tap on the input field and the keyboard re-opens.  (To clarify: regular tapping does **nothing** for me...I could tap it all day long and it just stays closed.  It's the act of doing a solid, clean double-tap which seems to instantly being it back.)

I have no idea why this happens, but maybe this will help you too.